# mex made from c code crashes in loop, but not when ran once

Tags: c, matlab, memory, mex, calloc

I have a function written in C that i turn into a matlab executible (mex file). The C-function works fine when called once from matlab's command line, however when called 1000+ times in a for-loop it spontaneously crashes. This happens even if I feed it the same input at each iteration of the for-loop.

I am afraid I have a lurking c-bug. some issue with repeated memory allocation but I dont know enough c to fix it :(

I have narrowed the problem down to the WHILE loop in the below code (if the whole while-loop is commented out prior to compiling the problem goes away). Please help!

```
    #include "mex.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int sum_array(double a[], int from ,int to);
    // to compile this code in matlab do: mex -v ranksort.c

   void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray  *prhs[]){
           #define B_OUT       plhs[0]
           #define A_IN        prhs[0]

           int i,j,count,M,N; //declare some integers
           double *list,*sort_list,*rank_idx,*sort_idx,*ranksOrigOrder;//declare some pointers to doubles which will be allocated dynamically
           int *rank_list,*tielocs,*orig_indices;

           //set values based on input:
           M=mxGetM(A_IN);//get input row num
           N=mxGetN(A_IN);//get input col num
           if (M>N)
                 count=M; //get dimensions of A (columns...data must always be in columns)
           else
                 count=N;

           list =mxGetPr(A_IN); //grab data from pointer to inputted data
           sort_list = calloc(count,sizeof(double)); //allocate size and fill w/zeros all my 'double' arrays
           rank_idx =calloc(count,sizeof(double));
           sort_idx=calloc(count,sizeof(double));
           ranksOrigOrder=calloc(count,sizeof(double));
           tielocs =calloc(count+2,sizeof(double));
           orig_indices=calloc(count,sizeof(int)); //allocate size and fill w/ zeros all my 'int' arrays
           rank_list =calloc(count,sizeof(int));

            if (sort_list==NULL||tielocs==NULL||rank_list==NULL||orig_indices==NULL||ranksOrigOrder==NULL||rank_idx==NULL||list==NULL){ puts ("Error (re)allocating memory"); exit (1); }

           B_OUT = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M, N, mxREAL); //create a matlab-style struct for output...
           ranksOrigOrder = mxGetPr(B_OUT); // set in-code variable to its pointer

           /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ CODE BODY STARTS HERE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
           /*Calculate the rank for each element in the arr_list*/
           for(i=0; i<count; i++){
                 for(j=0; j<i; j++){
                     if(list[i] >= list[j])
                           rank_list[i]++;
                     else
                           rank_list[j]++;
                  }
            }

           for(i=0; i<count; i++){
               sort_list[rank_list[i]] = list[i];
               orig_indices[rank_list[i]] =i;
               sort_idx[i]=i+1;
           }
           int tiesIdx=0; int *ties = NULL;
           for (i=0; i<count-1;i++){
                 if (sort_list[i]>= sort_list[i+1]){
                 ties = (int*) realloc (ties, (tiesIdx) *sizeof(int));       //reallocate size of array
                 if (ties==NULL){ puts ("Error (re)allocating memory"); exit (1); }
                  ties[tiesIdx]=i; //add location of tie to newly grown array  
                   tiesIdx++; //found a tie
                  }
           }
           // // append 2 after last element to ties
           ties = (int*) realloc (ties, (tiesIdx) * sizeof(int));         

           //reallocate size of array
           if (ties==NULL){ puts ("Error (re)allocating memory"); exit (1);           }
           ties[tiesIdx]=count+1;
           tiesIdx++;

           int tiecount=0; //step thru all the found ties

           // NO IN-LOOP CRASHING if this while loop is commented out....
           while (tiecount<tiesIdx){
                 int tiestart =ties[tiecount]; //grab this tie to check if it is one of a pair or a member of an island of consecutives
                 int ntied=2;

                 while (ties[tiecount+1] == ties[tiecount] + 1){                         //while it's a consecutive one...
                        tiecount++;
                        ntied++;
                 }
                 double mysum = (double)sum_array(sort_idx,tiestart,tiestart+ntied)/(double)ntied;        

                 for (int t=tiestart; t<tiestart+ntied;t++){
                       sort_idx[t]=mysum;
                  }
                 tiecount++;
           }

           for (i=0; i<count;i++){
                ranksOrigOrder[orig_indices[i]]=sort_idx[i];
           }

           free(sort_list);
           free(tielocs);
           free(rank_list);
           free(orig_indices);
           free(rank_idx);
           free(sort_idx);
           return;
   }
    int sum_array(double a[], int from ,int to){
        int i, sum=0;
        for (i=from; i<to; i++){
               sum = sum + (int)a[i];
         }
        return(sum);
     }
```

Comment: You have a memory leakage on `ranksOrigOrder` that it is not `free()`.

Comment: Don't use `puts`/`exit` use `mexErrMsgIdAndTxt` instead. Also use `mxCalloc` and `mxFree` instead of `calloc` and `free`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this chunk of code:

```
 // // append 2 after last element to ties
 ties = (int*) realloc (ties, (tiesIdx) * sizeof(int));

 //reallocate size of array
 if (ties==NULL){ puts ("Error (re)allocating memory"); exit (1);           }
 ties[tiesIdx]=count+1;
 tiesIdx++;

 int tiecount=0; //step thru all the found ties

 // NO IN-LOOP CRASHING if this while loop is commented out....
 while (tiecount<tiesIdx){
```

Your are re-allocating space for `tiesIdx` element, and a little after you want to access `tiesIdx` position of the `ties` array. This is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of your array have to be indexed from 0 to `tiesIdx-1`

After that you inc `tiesIdx` by 1 and then perform a loop on that incremented var, that is obviously [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you will index array out of bounds.

Furthermore the inner loop:

```
       while (ties[tiecount+1] == ties[tiecount] + 1){                         //while it's a consecutive one...
              tiecount++;
              ntied++;
       }
```

is not checking for array bounds: if all elements of ties are consecutive you'll index the array out of bounds.

**NOTE**: You have a memory leakage on `ranksOrigOrder` that it is not `free()`.